# Getting Dataset, Dataadapter etc. in asp.net like we can get in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wonder if there is any way of getting datasets, dataadapters etc. in asp.net like we can get in vb.net, just by adding a binding source, giving it DataSource and then data member.
It gives you a statement like

```
 Me.taGetKey.Fill(Me.DsGetKey.tblLicense)
```

In the Form_load event of your form.
I want to avoid all the code that we need otherwise to get this.

I added a biding source to my asp.net application but it did not work the way we can do it vb.net.

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly but you may find `DataControls` (`GridView`, `DataList` etc) and `DataSource controls` (`SqlDataSource`, `ObjectDataSource` etc) in ASP.NET which provide facility to bind the DataSet or other datasources to the complex and simple controls.